# Close only one class when multiply divs has same name

Tags: jquery, html

I'm dynamically creating this tree, the problem is that since they all has the same class name, it close all the divs that are open.

I'm trying to use `$(this).parent().next('.sticker').hide();` but nothing happens. Am I using it wrong ?

```
    $('#note-btn').click(function() {
        $.get('xml/note.xml', function(data) {
            $(data).find('notes').each(function() {

                var notes = '<div class="notes">';

                notes += '<div class="notes-close">' + '</div>';
                $('#page-content-wrapper').append(notes);
            });

            $(".notes-close").click(function()
            {
                $(this).parent().next('.notes').toggle();
            });

        });

    });
});
```

The output of this is.

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
<div class="notes"> 
<div class="notes-close"></div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

where the note-close is the closing button for the notes,

Comment: How would we know if your selectors are correct if we can't see the associated HTML?

Comment: What tree are you referring to?

Comment: There is no HTML elements, since the structure is created with Jquery as you see in the post.

Comment: Where <div class="notes"> div is closing

Comment: Am I missing something? for each `note`, you build a string of tags in `sticker`.  What is `sticker` used for?

Comment: @MarcAudet Hi, well this is what Im creating.

<div class="notes">
<div class="notes-close"></div>
</div>
Where the close button is closing down the notes.

Comment: It looks more like `<div class="notes"><div class="notes-close"></div>` ... the file you are getting, where is the `data` being used?

Comment: at first glance your code has a couple of issues. .find() will return all descendant DOM elements that match your selector. 'notes' is not a valid selector in that it is not yet a DOM element. Without knowing the data that your xml file returns i am just making assumptions here. var sticker creates a div w class notes without a closing tag. this line $('#page-content-wrapper').append(notes); is also incorrect as notes is not a variable you can append. you should replace it with sticker as that has the element you actually want to append to the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your close button should close the current note, so `.next()`/`.prev()` are not needed. You can use `.closest()` to travel up the DOM to the first `.notes` and `.toggle()` that.

replace:

```
$(this).parent().next('.notes').toggle();
```

with:

```
$(this).closest('.notes').toggle();
```

Comment: That did it. need to read some about the hierarchy functions :)
Thanks alot.